# How can I force format.ps1xml files to wrap columns?

Tags: xml, powershell, output

I have created a new custom table output for one of my functions and was hoping someone with better experience could help with a problem I am seeing.

I have a column width set for certain items in the table in the hope that they would wrap around at that point, but they do not appear to do this until the console window's width has filled. It then does it for the last column that would go off the screen only. Any further columns are omitted from the output.

Here's my ps1xml excerpt:

```xml
<View>
    <Name>L3Rule</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Show.L3Rule</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>
    <GroupBy>
        <ScriptBlock>
            $_.Name
        </ScriptBlock>
        <CustomControlName>RuleGrouping</CustomControlName>
    </GroupBy>
    <TableControl>
        <AutoSize />
        <TableHeaders>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>ID</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Action</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>30</Width>
                <Label>Source</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>30</Width>
                <Label>Destination</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>30</Width>
                <Label>Service</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Logged</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Tag</Label>
            </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
            <TableRowEntry>
                <Wrap/>
                <TableColumnItems>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>ID</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Action</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <ScriptBlock>
                            if ($_.Source -is [System.String]) { $_.Source }
                            else { $_.Source.Name -join "; " }
                        </ScriptBlock>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <ScriptBlock>
                            if ($_.Destination -is [System.String]) { $_.Destination }
                            else { $_.Destination.Name -join "; " }
                        </ScriptBlock>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <ScriptBlock>
                            if ($_.Service -is [System.String]) { $_.Service }
                            else { $_.Service.Name -join "; " }
                        </ScriptBlock>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Logged</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Tag</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                </TableColumnItems>
            </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
    </TableControl>
</View>
```

Here is an example of the output:

```bsh
     Rule: Inbound to blah


ID   Action Source      Destination Service             Logged Tag
--   ------ ------      ----------- -------             ------ ---
1111 allow  Somewhere   ANY         Service; Service    true   N/A


     Rule: Outbound to blah


ID   Action Source      Destination                             Service
--   ------ ------      -----------                             -------
2222 allow  Item1       Object1; AnotherObject1; MoreObjects    Service; Service (TCP); Service (TCP); Another
                                                                Service (TCP); This Service
```

As you can see it is omitting the last two columns and some of the columns are bigger than the 30 characters specified. I would like it if they wrapped as I expected them too, but I suspect the issue is that they only allow the wrap at a row entry level.

Ideally I would be able to use Out-String on the items being output. I have tried that to show the items like this, but I think it is forcing a default width to the columns. (I saw something similar in the DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml file - Line 3420)

```bsh
     Rule: Inbound to blah


ID   Action Source      Destination Service             Logged Tag
--   ------ ------      ----------- -------             ------ ---
1111 allow  Somewhere   ANY         Service             true   N/A
                                    Service


     Rule: Outbound to blah


ID   Action Source Destination    Service               Logged Tag
--   ------ ------ -----------    -------               ------ ---
2222 allow  Item1  Object1        Service               true   N/A      
                   AnotherObject1 Service (TCP)
                   MoreObjects    Service (TCP)
                                  Another Service (TCP)
                                  This Service
```

Hopefully I have provided enough information, but please let me know if there is more you need to know. Please tell me I'm doing something stupid.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. A combination of using Out-String, setting all the column sizes and removing the **AutoSize** tag helped massively.

If you wish to achieve something similar and found this page similarly frustrated, this is how you do it.

```
<View>
    <Name>L3Rule</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Show.L3Rule</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>
    <GroupBy>
        <ScriptBlock>
            $_.Name
        </ScriptBlock>
        <CustomControlName>RuleGrouping</CustomControlName>
    </GroupBy>
    <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>6</Width>
                <Label>ID</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>8</Width>
                <Label>Action</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>35</Width>
                <Label>Source</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>35</Width>
                <Label>Destination</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>18</Width>
                <Label>Service</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>6</Width>
                <Label>Logged</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Width>20</Width>
                <Label>Tag</Label>
                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
            </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
            <TableRowEntry>
                <Wrap/>
                <TableColumnItems>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>ID</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Action</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <ScriptBlock>
                            if ($_.Source -is [System.String]) { $_.Source }
                            else { $_.Source.Name | Out-String }
                        </ScriptBlock>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <ScriptBlock>
                            if ($_.Destination -is [System.String]) { $_.Destination }
                            else { $_.Destination.Name | Out-String }
                        </ScriptBlock>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <ScriptBlock>
                            if ($_.Service -is [System.String]) { $_.Service }
                            else { $_.Service.Name | Out-String }
                        </ScriptBlock>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Logged</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Tag</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                </TableColumnItems>
            </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
    </TableControl>
</View>
```